# поворот таблицы в postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, unpivot

В ПГ [есть функция](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/11/tablefunc.html) `crosstab` которая поворачивает таблицу с вертикальными категориями горизонтально. У меня есть таблица с горизонтальными категориями - хочу повернуть вертикально.

тоесть

```
id,cat1,cat2,cat3
---
 0,val1,val2,val3
 1,val4,val5,val6
```

развернуть как

```
id,cat,val
---
0,cat1,val1
0,cat2,val2
0,cat3,val3
1,cat1,val4
1,cat2,val5
1,cat3,val6
```

`crosstab` делает преобразование обратное нужному.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вроде красивое решение через `unnest`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW unpivott
 AS 
SELECT id
 , unnest(
    array['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'] 
    ) AS cat
 , unnest(
    array[cat1,cat2,cat3] 
    ) AS val
 FROM pivott;
```